# res.render not rendering all the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

When getting `/lego/sets` it renders all the data successfully but with query parameters like `/lego/sets/?theme=technic` it does not render correct, it just creates a single empty row of a table without any data

**server.js**

```
app.get("/lego/sets", (req, res) => {
  if(req.query.theme){
    legoData
    .getSetsByTheme(req.query.theme)
    .then((data) => {
      if (data.length > 0) {
        res.render("sets", {sets:data});
        console.log(data);
    }
      //res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(404).render("404");//sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/views/404.html"));


    });
  }
  else{
    legoData
    .getAllSets()
    .then((data) => {
     res.render("sets", {sets:data});
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('err')
      res.status(404).render("404");//sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/views/404.html"));

    });
     
  }
  
});
```

**sets.ejs**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=
    , initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <%- include('partials/navbar', {page: '/lego/sets'}) %>

    <div class="hero min-h-24 p-6 bg-base-200 md:container md:mx-auto">
        
          <div class="max-w-md">
            <h1 class="text-5xl font-bold">Collection</h1>
            <!-- <p class="py-6 text-5xl ">Error 404 you messed up</p> -->
          </div>
        
    </div>
<table class="flex justify-center">
       
        <tbody>
    
            <% sets.forEach((set)=>{ %>
                <tr>
                  
                        <td class="w-24 rounded">
                            <img class="w-24 p-2" src="<%= set.img_url %>">
                        </td>
                        
                        <td ><%= set.name %> </td>
                        <td ><a href="/lego/sets?theme=<%= set.theme %>" class="btn"><%= set.theme %></td>
                        <td ><%= set.year %></td>
                        <td class="pl-6 pr-6"><%= set.num_parts %></td>
                        
                        <td><a href="/lego/sets/<%= set.set_num %>" class="btn">Details</a></td>
                   
                </tr>
                <% }) %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  
</body>
</html>
```

all the routes are configured properly i also tried console logging from both sets.ejs and server.js and it does console logs the correct data.

Comment: Please add the `console.log(data)` output.

Comment: I have already done that its console logging data properly

Comment: Please add it in the question, so other people can see it and help you figure out what is wrong.